# How to notify calling Activity when SyncAdapter has finished?

Tags: android, callback, synchronization, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter

In my Android project I use a custom `SyncAdapter` which downloads data and stores it in local SQLite database.

```
public class CustomSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    public CustomSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account,
                              Bundle extras,
                              String authority,
                              ContentProviderClient provider,
                              SyncResult syncResult) {

        // 1) Download data via AsyncTask
        // 2) Store data via ContentProvider
    }
}
```

I schedule sychronization from the main `Activity` using the `ContentResolver` such as ...

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, Authentication.AUTHORITY, bundle);
```

Is there a common way the calling `Activity` is notified when the synchronization has finished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this with with `ContentResolver.notifyChange()`.

So in your `SyncAdapter` you would at something like this:

```
...
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account,
                          Bundle extras,
                          String authority,
                          ContentProviderClient provider,
                          SyncResult syncResult) {

    // 1) Download data via AsyncTask
    // 2) Store data via ContentProvider

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(<your_content_uri>, null, false);
}
...
```

In the Activity you then use `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity  {

    private ContentObserver mObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                // Do something.
            }
        };
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(<your_content_uri>, mObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mObserver);
    }
}
```

Comment: [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) requires to pass a handler. `notifyChange` is the same message which is already sent by the `ContentProvider` I guess?! Or which `Uri` do you use?

Comment: I added `Handler` to my response. Yes if your `ContentProvider` calls `notifyChange` you do not need to call it manually.

Comment: I think I have to leave out `Looper.getMainLooper` since I already run on the UI thread. Otherwise I end up in a `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`. - I guess you comment "Do nothing." should be something like "Update UI."

Comment: If you do not add `Looper.getMainLooper()` `Handler` will take looper from current thread. Which in your case is main looper. So this shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your activity you can add:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSyncMonitor = ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(
            ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_ACTIVE
                    | ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_PENDING,
            this
    );
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    ContentResolver.removeStatusChangeListener(mSyncMonitor);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public final void onStatusChanged(int which) {
    // TODO update activity data
}
```